# Identify web-objects from redundant URIs using HTTP requests

Tags: r, http, rcurl, httr

I am struggling with an ill-constructed web-server log file, which I want to summarize to analyse attendance of the hosted site. Unfortunately for me, the architecture of the site is messy, so that there are no indexes of the hosted objects (html pages, jpg images, pdf document, etc.) while several URIs can refer to the same page. For example :

- `http://www.site.fr/main.asp?page=foo.htm`
- `http://www.site.fr/storage-tree/foo.htm`
- `http://www.site.fr/specific.asp?id=200`
- `http://www.site.fr/specific.asp?path=/storage-tree/foo.htm`

etc. without any obvious regularities between the duplicate URIs.

**How, conceptually and pratically, can I efficiently identify the pages?** As I see the problem, the idea is to construct an index linking log's URIs with a unique-object identifier constructed from http requests. There are three loose constraints :

- I use R for the statistical part, and would therefore prefer to use it for http processing too
- logs consist in hundreds of thousands of different URIs (among which forms, search and database queries) so that rapidity might be a matter
- If I want to be able to tell, even in three days or a month, that this new URI is a known previously identified page, I have store the features I use to assess that two URIs refer to the same page. Then, storage space is a matter.

Comment: I am not completely sure that "rapidity matters". http requests are often quick : `library(RCurl) ; pages <- rep('http://www.insee.fr',100) ; system.time(reponses <- getURI(pages))` is processed in 0.5 sec, so that the entire log coul be treated in 500 sec, less than 10 minutes. This holds if `http://www.insee.fr` is representative of the whole site, which is not sure : the logs report that the average request took 54.5 ms, hiding the fact that most of the requests are more than 75% of the requests take less than 1 ms, while few ones take several minutes.

Comment: I had some ideas : 1) process different MIME type differently ; 2) for text types : store the n-th first characters of the page ; 3) for HTML files : use the title tag in the document head; 4) use only the header via HEAD http request for rapidity (but what then use to identify the object?)

Comment: Provided I have `RCUrl` package installed, for (1), I can filter by type with option `httpheader = c(Accept = "MIME type"))` in `getURI()` function ; for (2) I can use `data<-getURI(...)` and store `data[1:100]` ; for (3) I have `HTMLcode  <- getURL('http://www.insee.fr',.opts=curlOptions(followlocation=TRUE)) ; 
title <- regmatches(HTMLcode,regexec('<title>(.*)</title>',HTMLcode))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy with httr:

```
library(httr)
HEAD("http://gmail.com")$url
```

You will probably also want to check the `status_code` returned by HEAD, as failures often won't be redirected.

(One advantage of using httr over RCurl here is that it automatically preserves the connection across multiple http calls to the same site, which makes things quite a bit faster)

Comment: This is part of the answer, thanks. But the main point is that, in most cases, the redundant URIs are valid permanent URIs : **they are not redirected.** This comes from the fact that the ASP pages just grab HTML pages and cover them with different settings (e.g. banners, CSS, side columns), and that there can be several different calls (identifier, filters, path) for a single HTML page.

Comment: @Arthur Then there's nothing you can do except to construct some hash based on the page content.